# Custom user role with max participants and max rooms

Tags: bigbluebutton

I would like to add two new settings with user roles. I would like to limit users with a given max number of participants and a max number of rooms. I have installed bbb with greenlight on my Ubuntu 16.04 VPS.

At present there is a site-wide setting for max room. For this, at greenlight/app/views/admins/components/_settings.html.erb, there is :

```
<%= button_to admin_room_limit_path(limit: 15), class: "colorinput-input" do %><% end %>
```

This helps to control number of rooms.

But my problem is i would like to add this with a custom user role.

How to achieve this with the controller. I am able to bring into the views but not able to implement from the controller point of view. Implementing straight in the user role pushes site-wide setting instead of individual role.

Comment: I think you should ask here https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/issues